# phone gap download failing

Tags: github, cordova, download

I tried downloading phonegap version 2.9.0 from http://phonegap.com/install/ which links to https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.9.0.zip but it will fail every single time. It will download a few mb, and it will return network error. Tried downloading it using chrome and firefox but fail. I even tried using download manager in firefox (orbit), but it will still fail with the same message, network error.

I can download files from every other place in the internet, files that are much larger than this phonegap file. I have tried to download this file for the past 3 days and failed. Previously (about a month ago) I have no problem downloading this phonegap library.

Can anyone shed light to me why is this happening?

Comment: No clue, works fine here.

Comment: Just tried it and did not have any issues. Can you try from another network?

Comment: thanks for checking man,, but it still fails  after downloading like 5mbs of the file,, looks like Git-hub is having issues in my area.. is there away you could download it and post it for me some where with drop-box or any other cloud hosting service.. and post the link,, so that i can download it from there?